# Displaying ApexPages.Messages on redirected VisualForce Page

Tags: apex, pagereference

I hope this is a simple problem and I'm just missing something.

My Controller is something like this

```
public pagereference processtempcon(){
    //some code here
    delete record;
    pagereference p = apexpages.Currentpage();
    p.setredirect(true);
    apexpages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info,'Total Number of Records Processed:' + selectedtempcon.size());
    apexpages.addmessage(msg);
    return p; 
}
```

Which is not supported.Any Idea on this

Comment: Just remove `p.setredirect(true);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to reload the page an show some info in the message box. The `setRedirect(true)` parameter removes the info you want to show:

> If set to true, a redirect is performed through a client side
>   redirect. This type of redirect performs an HTTP GET request, **and flushes the view state**

I have created a simple example and it works fine:

Controller:

```
public with sharing class test1{
    public Integer myInt { get; set; }
    public test1(){
        myInt = 0;
    }
    public pagereference processtempcon(){
        pagereference p = apexpages.Currentpage();
        apexpages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info,'Total Number of reloads: ' + (myInt++));
        apexpages.addmessage(msg);
        return p; 
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="test1">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:messages/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!processtempcon}" value="Reload"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: If i remove `p.setredirect(true)`,the deleted record is also existing in the redirected page.But here I don't wanna show the deleted record in the redirected Page

Comment: @EagerinSf In your code you are reading the entries from the database into the list. Then you delete one record. Why don't you just refresh a list with records after delete? Something like: `delete record; listWithRecords = [select x, y, From MyObject__c]; return null;`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to re-run the constructor you might be better off not returning a page reference in your function.  It has the same result as returning the page reference for the current page.  For example

```
public void processtempcon(){
    //some code here
    ApexPages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info,'Total Number of Records Processed:' + selectedtempcon.size());
    Apexpages.addMessage(msg); 
}
```

If you want to selectively return users to a different page or to the same page you can switch from a void return type to a PageReference return type, but just return null.  For example

```
public PageReference processtempcon(){
    //some code here
    if(selectTempCon.isEmpty()) {
       return Page.AnotherPage;
    } else {
      ApexPages.Message msg = new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Info,'Total Number of Records Processed:' + selectedtempcon.size());
      ApexPages.addmessage(msg);
      return null; // keeps the user on the current page
    } 
}
```

Comment: Here Once the records are Processed, I need to delete the processed Records and show the Remaining Records, which are present in the same Page.